# Make a riddle using a .exe

Tags: python, c++, exe, reverse-engineering

Im trying to create a riddle, but from what I can tell, if the answers are in the code, someone could reverse engineer the .exe to get the answers. Is there any way I could hide it in the code, or make some kind of encryption to make it impossible to get the code from the .exe? I usually code in python and I'm using pyinstaller to make the app, but I've had some experience with C++ and I think I could use it to create the app if necessary. Thanks in advance, and sorry for any possible grammar mistakes.

Comment: ***or make some kind of encryption to make it impossible to get the code from the .exe?*** Yes you could make it difficult to get the text by encryption

Comment: It's impossible to 100% hide code. At some point, code needs to be decrypted/unpacked/whatever in order for the machine to execute the instructions. It's just a matter of how hard you want it to be.

Comment: I don't know of any code obfuscation method that is foolproof. You can only make it more time consuming for an attacker.

Answer (score 0):

`pyinstaller` already has a built-in mechanism to prevent reverse-engineering executables. See https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#hiding-the-source-code for more information. Another possible option, recommended by `pyinstaller`, is to use Cython to compile your code from C into machine code. `Pyinstaller` also suggests using AES256 to encrypt the resulting Python bytecode to prevent "casual tampering."

Comment: Although, again, this just makes it harder. If someone's determined, they could open your app in a debugger, or take a snapshot of memory while the program is running.